# Powershell/Windows: How to extract zip file without FIRST folder level

Tags: windows, powershell, directory, zip

I'd like to extract a zip file with a folder structure, but without the first level, e.g.:

```
ZIP --> Folder1
            --> Folder1.1
            --> Folder1.2
```

Currently, when using Expand-Archive cmdlet, there seems to be no option for this.

Is there an easy way to do this on Windows? On a linux box I use bsdtar to achieve this:
I'd like to extract a zip file with a folder structure, but without the first level, e.g.:

```
ZIP --> Folder1
            --> Folder1.1
            --> Folder1.2
```

Currently, when using Expand-Archive cmdlet, there seems to be no option for this.

Is there an easy way to do this on Windows? On a linux box I use

```
bsdtar --strip-components=1 -xvf Java/Java11.zip --directory=Java
```

Thx

Thx

Comment: If there is a folder in the .zip, you'll get that folder out the other end, too. If you were willing to create a function with more code to work around this, it's achievable. But I do not see an option to workaround this using just `Expand-Archive`. I wonder if anyone else knows a cool solution using PowerShell. If there was, it _might_ involve using a .NET method, which would never be comparable to a UNIX tool in terms of friendlyness at the command line.